# laravel 5.3 how to make select option default to empty

Tags: laravel-5.3

i have song table which have relationship with category and album tables
when i want to insert new song this field populate automatic, but i want to be empty as defualt.

this is song controller create method.

```
public function create()
    {
        //
        $artists = Artist::all();
        $categories = Category::all();
        $albums = Album::all();
        return view('admin.songs.create', compact('categories', 'albums', 'artists'));
    }
```

and this is my view.

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="artist">Select Category</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="category" name="category_id">
                        @foreach($categories as $category)
                        <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{$category->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="album">Select Album</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="album" name="album_id">
                        @foreach($albums as $album)
                            <option value="{{ $album->id }}">{{ $album->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
```

what i want is category and album option values to be empty by defualt not to populate automatically.

Comment: You mean that by default nothing is selected? Just add empty <option> before foreach

Comment: yeah i mean nothing is selected.  you mean like this <option value=""><option>

Comment: just add <option value=""></option> in front each foreach

Comment: thanks @Bostjan it works